# Problem Installing Ruby 1.9.2 alone in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, installation

I have pre installed ruby 1.8.7 available in my ubuntu pc. Since i am going to start my development in ruby 1.9.2, i have uninstalled ruby 1.8.7 and installed the fresh copy of the 1.9.2 using the following command.

```
  sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.2
```

It is installed successfully. But i cant able to bring the REPL (irb) to the shell. I am new to both linux and ruby. Can someone clarify me what should i do next?

And i know we can do this simply in RVM. Since i am going to work on only the 1.9.2 version, its not required.

Comment: There are many advantages to RVM beyond installing multiple Rubies. Check into RVMs gemsets.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install irb1.9
```

should do the trick. What you should *really* do for 1.9 development is:

```
apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full --no-install-recommends
```

which includes everything you'll need.

Comment: That's not good - Ruby 1.9.2 is the preferred version, and Ruby 1.9.1 is not fully supported by the community. I've just checked the package list for Ubuntu, and they are indeed offering 1.9.1, so it's probably better to use RVM rather than the distribution packages.

Comment: @Stuart Ellis: The latest version of the `ruby1.9.1` package *is* 1.9.2, and has been for quite some time (since Ubuntu 10.04 "Lucid", i.e. almost a year), as has been discussed numerous times both here on StackOverflow and on the Ruby mailinglist(s).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you might have to make a symlink that points irb1.9.1 to irb

```
ln -s /usr/bin/irb1.9.1 /usr/bin/irb
```